# Getting jmeter aggregate report information into variables

Tags: testing, load, reporting, jmeter

I am using jmeter to run a series of tests against a web application, mostly web services hosted from Jboss and soon to be Tomcat.

Most of the tests I do run autonomously and I typically write results to a reporting database.

I am trying to find a way to get the information that is displayed in the aggregate report (average, median, max etc..) assigned to variables.

If I can get these values into variables I can then write them to my reporting database and/or perform calculations with them.

The aggregate report is giving me exactly the information that I want, but I don't want to have to manually move the data to a reporting system if I can get away with it.

Comment: I found a way to do it.

Using a BSF Listener placed after each sampler I want to monitor I can use this code

theTime = sampleResult.getTime();<br>
theTimeString = theTime.toString();<br>
vars.put("report.loginTime", theTimeString);

This gives me the time in milliseconds it took for the prior sample to complete, I can record all of this in my reporting system and just calculate the median and average on my own.

I realize there may be a more elegant solution and that a real programmer could probably do all of that on a single line, but I do what I can.

Comment: IT looks like a kind of "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: Using a command line invocation:
jmeter-hp.bat -n -t %1.jmx -l %2.jtl


The -l option create a jtl file that include most of the data you need for each sample.


The output format can be controlled via jmeter.properties file.
Have a look at:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui
and
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is configure Aggregate Report to write the output to file. After test completion you should be able to load data to database as follows (MS SQL Example)

```
USE your_schema;
GO

BULK INSERT dbo.your_schema
FROM 'path_to_your_csv_results_file'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

If you want more flexibility I would suggest using JSR223 Post Processor and Groovy as language to fetch previous sampler details.

There is a pre-defined variable called `prev` which stands for [SampleResult](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class - see linked JavaDoc on available methods. You can extract required values and store them to JMeter Variables like:

```
vars.put("StartTime", String.valueOf(prev.getStartTime()));
```

and then process variables as you wish.

The reason of choosing JSR223 instead of Javascript, BSF, Beanshell, whatever is that JSr223 Sampler in case of Groovy language and compilation caching enabled which gives performance almost equal to native Java code.

- [JMeter JSR223 recommendation explanation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Comparison Benchmark of JMeter Scripting engines](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)